# Python sklearn.linear_model: LinearRegression() ValueError occured when .predict()

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, scikit-learn, linear-regression

My training matrix X has shape (5182, 19231) and y is a list of 1s and 0s with length 5182. My test matrix has shape (496, 5477). I stored them in seperate pickle files. Here is my code:

```
def read(pklFile1):
    f=open(pklFile1, 'rb')
    Y = cPickle.load(f)
    f.close()
    return Y
if __name__ == '__main__':
    X=read("results/train_feature.pkl")
    y=read("results/train_label.pkl")
    test=read("results/test_feature.pkl")
    target=read("test_label.pkl")
    clf=LogisticRegression()
    clf=clf.fit(X, y)
    predicted= clf.predict(test)
    accuracy=np.mean(predicted == target)
    print accuracy
```

When I run my code, the following message occured when running
`predicted = clf.predict(test)`:

> `ValueError: X has 5477 features per sample; expecting 19231`

How can I fix it?

Comment: The number of features mismatch between training and predicting phase, you cannot ask your model to predict with less or more features than the number of features that was used in the training phase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You trained a linar model on 19231 features, but want to predict some new sample with only 5477 features. **That's not how linear models work (or most of the classifiers)**. The number of features need to be the same!

How should your linear model, which consists of a linear combination of 19231 variables work on only 5477 variables? If some vars are unknown during prediction, you could impute them (e.g. setting to zero or mean), but even this approach needs to know the exact mapping of your variables. Which variable in train corresponds to which in predict.